# Can I add an element to a RepeatingView without refreshing the latter?

Tags: wicket

Let's say that I have a RepeatingView with complex elements (for example containing applets). I want to add (or delete) a new element to RepeatingView with ajax, but I don't want to refresh all the elements, because it would cause applets to reload, which I obviously don't want.

I am using wicket 1.4.18

Adding to target only the element that I want to add, does not work, I get:
`Component with id (...) was not found while trying to perform markup update. Make sure you called component.setOutputMarkupId(true) on the component whose markup you are trying to update`

Comment: Have you tried anything already?  Seems like you might be able to add the new component to the AjaxRequestTarget instead of the entire list, but I haven't tried.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that already, it does not work, I get `Component with id (...) was not found while trying to perform markup update. Make sure you called component.setOutputMarkupId(true) on the component whose markup you are trying to update.`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at the approach suggested in this Wicket in Action article: [Repainting only newly-created repeater items via ajax](http://wicketinaction.com/2008/10/repainting-only-newly-created-repeater-items-via-ajax/)

The problem when you want to add a new element via AJAX is that there's no root markup tag for  the newly added item for Wicket to repaint it.

Quoting the article:

> The trick is to give Wicket a tag to repaint via Ajax which can be
>   accomplished by doing the following:
>
> 1. create the markup tag to represent the new item
> 2. add it to the right place in the markup
> 3. have Wicket repaint it via Ajax

The code in the article basically prepends some javascript in the ajax submit button's callback that actually creates the markup with the appropriate id for Wicket to be able to replace the element later, when you add it to the `AjaxRequestTarget`.

Comment: Took me to long to find it on the Wicket in Action website. You keep on beating me to it today ;)

Comment: Well, not bad idea, I'll try this. I guess similar thing can be done to delete an element.

Comment: @Adam take a look at this other article, too: [Building a ListEditor form component](http://wicketinaction.com/2008/10/building-a-listeditor-form-component/). This will help you building a `RepeatingView` that does atomic form updates. That is, not updating the `Model` in every intermediate add or delete, only on form submission.

Comment: @Xavi, actually I don't use form here, however thanks for the second article, might be useful for other situations. And your solution from the first article works just perfectly! I've added removing to it and have exactly what I wanted. Following this, I accept your answer :)