# add row to refreshingView without repainting entire refreshingView

Tags: wicket

We have a `refreshingView<shirt>` (contained inside a border) set up and outside of the refreshing view we have an ajaxLink that adds a new shirt object to the list that backs the refreshingView.  The refreshingView contains textFields and dropdowns for the user to enter information in about the shirts.

Inside the ajaxLink we add a shirt to the list and then add the entire border to the target of the ajaxLink, thus refreshing the border.  The problem occurs when you add a row and fill out the information ( shirt color, size, style, etc. ) and add another shirt.  Another row for a new shirt is added, but at the same time all the information that was inputted about the first shirt is lost.

Any ideas on how to retain the information of the previously entered shirts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The previous data is lost, because a refreshingView discards all Items (and the models containing the data) after each rendering.

You can set an ItemReuseStrategy:

```
refreshingView.setItemReuseStrategy(new ReuseIfModelsEqualStrategy());
```

Another, more involved way is to only redraw the newly added row. See the answer here: [Can I add an element to a RepeatingView without refreshing the latter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807514/can-i-add-an-element-to-a-repeatingview-without-refreshing-the-latter)

Comment: Rather than create a new instance of the strategy class each time via

`new ReuseIfModelsEqualStrategy()` 

it's preferable to use

`ReuseIfModelsEqualStrategy.getInstance()`

so that the same instance can be shared across all RefreshingView objects that your app ever uses.

Of course ReuseIfModelsEqualStrategy is immutable and threadsafe so there's no issue with using a shared instance.